# php mongodb library abortTransaction doest't work

Tags: php, mongodb, transactions

i'm trying to learn mongodb transactions using php-mongodb library v1.5 but  i've found some problemes.

i've tried to start, commit, and abort transaction using the giving methods but abortTransaction is not working for me :

```
    $session = self::$instance->startSession();

    $this->db = self::$instance->{"mydb"};

    $session->startTransaction();

    $this->db->users->deleteOne([

        '_id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId('5c88e197df815495df201a38')
    ]);

    $session->abortTransaction();

    $session->endSession();
```

the transaction is always commited even after the abort action !!!

what i'm missing here please save my day :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the transaction is always commited even after the abort action

This is because the delete operation doesn't utilise the `session` object that you have instantiated. You need to pass the `session` as a `$options` parameter [MongoDB\Collection::deleteOne()](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-deleteOne/). Otherwise it will execute outside of the transaction. For example:

```
$session->startTransaction();
$this->db->users->deleteOne(
   ['_id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId('5c88e197df815495df201a38')], 
   ['session' => $session]
);
```

See also [MongoDB Transactions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/) for more information